# select the last 700 entry in my access database and the 10 first words from a memo field

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

the code from the last 700 is this

```
private string strsqlcommandBeta = 
    "select top 700 * from objectaer  " +
    " order by objectdate desc";
```

and the code for the first 10 words of the memo field called patronvalue17 should be this.

```
private string strsqlcommandBeta = "select LEFT(patronvalue17, INSTR(10, patronvalue17, " ") - 1)  from objectaer  " + " order by objectdate desc" + "  ";
```

I don't know how to put this together

this code give the next error

```
select top 700 LEFT(patronvalue17, INSTR(10, patronvalue17, ' ') - 1)  * from objectaer
```

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'LEFT(patronvalue17, INSTR(10, patronvalue17, ' ') - 1)  *'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott found the syntactic bug. The reason why you're not getting the 10 words is because that's not how INSTR works. Its signature is

```
INSTR(Start_Posn, String_Being_Searched, Sought_String_Item, Compare_Type)
```

meaning you're looking up the first space after character 10 and then getting everything to the left of that. Normally that means you're getting 2-3 words out, rather than 10.

If you're getting all the memo text out that sounds very strange to me, but is indicative that  InStr fails to match your space character and returns the index of the last character. I'd try supplying a comparetype.

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/instr.php

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing a ',' character between your two selected fields.  -1), *

Comment: the error just stopped, but for some reason I'm getting all the words from the memo field, not only the first 10 with that code